# Cannot locate installation of package actionlib_tutorials

Tags: ros, actionlib-tutorials, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow along with the tutorial at http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android to allow an android app to control a robot running ROS. I am getting an error requesting installation of the package actionlib_tutorials.

I cant find any info about such a package on the ROS wiki. The closest thing to it is commons/actionlib. Is there a different stack that I need to update or install to get this working?

The traceback and error are posted below:

### rosrun rosjava_bootstrap make.py actionlib_java
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 108, in 
main(sys.argv)
File "/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 100, in main
build(rospack, package)
File "/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 57, in build
maven.write_ant_maven_dependencies(rospack, package, stream)
File "/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 298, in write_ant_maven_dependencies
_write_maven_dependencies_group(rospack, package, 'compile', stream)
File "/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 255, in _write_maven_dependencies_group
_map_package_dependencies(rospack, package, export_operator, scope=scope)
File "/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 105, in _map_package_dependencies
_map_exports(rospack, dependency, export_operator, _transtive_dependency_scope_check, scope)
File "/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 86, in _map_exports
package_directory = roslib.packages.get_pkg_dir(package)
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/packages.py", line 220, in get_pkg_dir
raise InvalidROSPkgException("Cannot locate installation of package %s: %s. ROS_ROOT[%s] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[%s]"%(package, rperr.strip(), ros_root, ros_package_path))
roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException: Cannot locate installation of package actionlib_tutorials: [rospack] couldn't find package [actionlib_tutorials]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/steve/ROS_DIR/turtlebot:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/appmanwx:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_voice_recognition:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_android:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_pr2_props:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_pan_tilt:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_map_nav:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_make_a_map:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_map_manager:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_app_chooser:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/android_teleop:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/appmanandroid:/home/steve/ROS_DIR/rosjava_core:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package actionlib_java written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/steve/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120117-184449/actionlib_java/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< actionlib_java [FAIL] [ 0.26 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package actionlib_java.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 54 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/steve/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120117-184449

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12669/cannot-locate-installation-of-package-actionlib_tutorials/) by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install the stack `common_tutorials`? It contains `actionlib_tutorials`.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-common-tutorials
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-18**:
That was it. Thank you.